# could anyone suggest me a simple way of splitting names in C++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to split a name into first and last name, but I'm sure my implementation is not the best one as far as simplicity.

```
string name = "John Smith";
    string first;
    string last (name, name.find(" "));//getting lastname
    for(int i=0; i<name.find(" "); i++)
    {
        first += name[i];//getting firstname
    }
    cout << "First: "<< first << " Last: " << last << endl;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know you're probably writing this for a simple use, but you should be aware that splitting names can be dicey; there are two-word surnames, surnames that come first, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using the [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method from string to split things up combined with find:

```
std::string name = "John Smith"
std::size_t pos = name.find(" ");
std::cout << "First: " << name.substr(0, pos) << " Last: " << name.substr(pos, std::string::npos) << std::endl;
```

where I've also used the `std::string::npos` to indicate the last position of a string.  Techincally, I could just get away with `name.substr(pos)` as `npos` is the default parameter.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string) SO post about string splitting.  You'll find better items there, like mention of the Boost split function.

Comment: Nice solution. But if not using "using namespace std;", you should also prefix "string" and "cout" with the "std::" thingy, no?

Comment: hey, I second that! great solution.... when I first started looking for a solution, the link you posted was the one I come across, but I couldn't make it work with my specific string....Thanks

Comment: What happens to all the middle names. As a result I would use find_first_of() to find the end of the first name and find_last_of() to find the beginning of the last name.

Comment: @Martin York in truth I would not use my solution if I had to actually split names.  There are multiple examples where names aren't <word> <word> in shape, i.e. in Spain they generally have two last names, one from the father and one from the Mother.  A name splitting engine would have a ton of rules.  I am assuming his question revolved around but a simple pairing.

Comment: @wheaties: True. Given the simple requirements from the OP your solution holds. Just be careful of extra spaces on the front of the string and note words are generally split by `White Space` not just the `Space Character`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are undetermined number of leading, trailing, and in-between spaces (and/or tabs), then the following is a very clean (but not necessarily most efficient) alternative that I can suggest:

```
std::istringstream ssname( name ); // needs <sstream> header
string first, last;
ssname >> first >> last;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try

```
strtok
```

function to split the string, code will be clean

Comment: strtok is very messy. It modifies the input string (which in C++ is not nice as we try and stay const correct).

Answer (score 0):

@ Akhil :: I would not recommend to use strtok in a c++ program as it cannot be used to run multiple instances of strtok as it uses a static variable in its implementation. Well you can ofcourse use it if you are going to use a single instance at any point of time..but better to go with c++ design patterns wheb you are using c++ :)

Answer (score 0):

Extending the idea by sly:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    std::string             name    = "   Martin Paul Jones   ";
    std::string::size_type  s       = name.find_first_not_of(" \t\n\r");
    std::string::size_type  e       = name.find_last_not_of(" \t\n\r");
    std::string             trim    = name.substr(s, (e - s + 1));
    std::string             first   = trim.substr(0, trim.find_first_of(" \t\n\r"));
    std::string             last    = trim.substr(trim.find_last_of(" \t\n\r") + 1);

    std::cout << "N(" << name << ") " << " T(" << trim << ") First(" << first << ") Last(" << last << ")\n";

    // Alternative using streams
    std::stringstream       namestream(name);
    namestream >> first >> last;
    while(namestream >> last) { /* Empty */ } // Skip middle names
    std::cout << "N(" << name << ")  First(" << first << ") Last(" << last << ")\n";
}
```

Try:

```
> g++ xx.cpp
> ./a.out
N(   Martin Paul Jones   )  T(Martin Paul Jones) First(Martin) Last(Jones)
N(   Martin Paul Jones   )  First(Martin) Last(Jones)
```